# How do I troubleshoot a CiviMail / Mail report?

Tags: civimail, civireport

I have a mail report that we use on our dashboard that is just taking forever to load. Using developer tools, I can't seem to figure it out.

`[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #_qf_Summary_submit: (More info: https://goo.gl/9p2vKq)  /civicrm/report/instance/33?reset=1&output=criteria:1`

The only thing I can find in the logs is `[warning] Deprecated function CRM_Core_BAO_Cache::cleanKey, use CRM_Utils_Cache::cleanKey` but I think that is unrelated.

It takes about 5 minutes to load a report of 28 emails.